# NodeJS module function convention - calling own functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

Say I have a module in Node that has two functions `func1()` and `func2()`. Func1 needs to make a call to func2 during its execution.

I want to have func2 in the exports so it can be individually tested, so I am setting the exports module exports to include both `func1` and `func2`:

```
(function (module) {

    module.func1= function (something) {

        var result = module.func2(something);

        return result + something;    
    }

    module.func2 = function(something) {

        return something * something;
    }
})(module.exports);
```

The question is.. **Is this the best way of defining / calling func2**?

I can't think of any other way of doing it but making a call to `module.func2()` just seems a little wrong to me for some reason.

**Update: to elaborate further:**

It seems that by using `module.func2` I am really calling `module.exports.func2` which is going out of the class to come back in again rather than keeping it all internal..

No other reason really, I appreciate that this works, I was just wondering if this was the generally accepted setup in Node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `this` instead of `module`, like this

```
....
var result = this.func2(something);
...
```

Comment: great, that seems much more sensible!